# Download video from URL and store it in android device

Tags: java, android, video

I have below code to download video from URL:

String videoUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hS5CfP8n_js";

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    private final int TIMEOUT_CONNECTION = 5000;//5sec
    private final int TIMEOUT_SOCKET = 30000;//30sec
    private String TAG = "TAG";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Downloading...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            url = new URL(videoUrl);
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.i(TAG, "video download beginning: " + videoUrl);

            //Open a connection to that URL.
            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

            //this timeout affects how long it takes for the app to realize there's a connection problem
            ucon.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
            ucon.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_SOCKET);


            //Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
            // uses 3KB download buffer
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(is, 1024 * 5);
            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).toString()+"/new.mp4");
            byte[] buff = new byte[5 * 1024];

            //Read bytes (and store them) until there is nothing more to read(-1)
            int len;
            while ((len = inStream.read(buff)) != -1) {
                outStream.write(buff, 0, len);
            }

            //clean up
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            inStream.close();

            Log.i(TAG, "download completed in "
                    + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000)
                    + " sec");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.v("TEST", result);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Video file is there in folder. But, when I tried to play it in media player it's not playing. Is there anything wrong in code?

Comment: please change `e.printStackTrace();` to `Log.e(TAG, "Exception", e);` and report what errors logcat says.

Comment: There is no exception message in there.

Comment: also,  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hS5CfP8n_js is not a url to a video,  its a url to a webpage that plays a video

Comment: How to get the URL from youtube by which we can download the video?

Comment: Sorry...thats not a programming question.  Try googling or searching on stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //make sure to call it from a suspend function or coroutine   
      
    private suspend fun downloadVideo(videoUrl: String): File? = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                try {
                    val url = URL(videoUrl)
                    val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                    connection.doInput = true
                    connection.connect()
        
                    val inputStream = connection.inputStream
                    val fileName = "downloaded_video.mp4" // Set the desired file name
                    val file = File(context?.cacheDir, fileName) // Store the video in the app's cache directory
        
                    FileOutputStream(file).use { output ->
                        val buffer = ByteArray(4 * 1024) // 4KB buffer
                        var bytesRead: Int
                        while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
                            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                        }
                        output.flush()
                    }
        
                    file
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    null
                }
            } 
     

//by mohammed shahbaz
```